# Translate Google Analytics ID into Report URL

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on an administration panel where the users can enter the Google Analytics ID for the site they are logged into. I'd like to present a link to the Google Analytics Report to the admin user in the admin panel as well, but I don't see how I can translate a tracking ID to a report URL.

So it would be like: `http://analytics.google.com/report/[Goggle Analytics ID]`

Does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "report ID" is a bit of a misnomer.  It actually specifies the particular data set (property and filters).   Multiple reports can be generated with the same report ID.  So it would be appropriate to ask users for their "report ID".

I do that on a Google Analytics time period portal that I created for myself and have made available to others: http://ostermiller.org/calc/ga.html  Once you enter a report ID, you can get quick links to various time period reports in Google Analytics.  I wrote that page because I find that changing the time period within Analytics is much harder than it should be.

Comment: so I can't use my tracking id to create a report URL?

Comment: No, you need to get your "report id" from an existing Google Analytics report.